# Is this appropriate to create a class with one method?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, static

I'm wondering whether it's a good practice to produce the code which being used like this:

```
new TemplateProcessor(inputStream).processTemplate("output-path.xhtml");
```

Here, TemplateProcessor contains only **one public method**. It seems the code above can be expressed with a static method, but I would like to avoid that. The reason is simple: object may contain encapsulated state, (maybe now, maybe in the future). Dear experts what would You prefer in this case?

Comment: If an object carries a state, then a class seems to be the way to go. Utility static methods only seem a good way when no state is being carried around.

Comment: Future proof code is good code

Comment: @skiwi Static methods have not seemed good since I've started using DI/IoC .. :>

Comment: Anyway, as far as the code: I would keep the *stream* separate and pass that to the method explicitly (unless the TemplateProcessor is itself a stream and designed to be used as such), even if it's not a static method. This allows more obvious control of the stream lifetime independent of the TemplateProcessor lifetime - let the caller deal with it, *when* it is needed. This makes TemplateProcessor easier to pass around between methods and stored in members or whatnot (without worrying about stream lifetimes) as well as makes it more practical to use with DI/IoC; c'mon, just one try ;-)

Comment: The following is from the String class: `return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();`

Comment: I think this proves the comment from user2864740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reasonable to encapsulate the code in a static method, with static imports it becomes very easy to use:

```
processTemplate(inputStream, "output-path.xhtml");
```

The above static method would just be a façade, a *convenience method* to be used for that specific *use case* that your class is solving, supposedly one that's very common. It does not prevent the class from evolving, even adding state. For more specialized use cases, the consumers can still create instances of the class and use its methods as usual.

To make that separation even more pronounced, you could add the static method to a sibling class, like `TemplateProcessorFacade`, which is a non-instantiatable utility class:

```
public final class TemplateProcessorFacade {
  private TemplateProcessorFacade() {}
  public static void processTemplate(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class should be seen as an object or module that performs a key role or function in the program. A role that no other class or module fulfils. For example, you can have a class `Animal` that provides the functions `sleep()`, `run()` . But you might want a class for carnivores which also `kill()` , `hunt()` etc. So you implement the `Carnivores` class by extending from `Animal`, which does what all variables of type `Animal` do, but also additionally kill and hunt.

If your class has only one public method, but if it's important for the design to have it as a separate module, then having a class for it is good. You can extend it later, if needed.

Also you can, keep the `sleep()` and `run()` functions static and public, all `Animal`'s do that, and so you can just do `Animal.sleep()` and such, without creating a separate instance. But a function like `roar()` shouldn't be.

**Update:**
The reason I said, `sleep()` and `run()` can be static is, there can be a class `Man` who also sleeps and runs.

The question to ask:

**Does it make sense to call `sleep()` and `run()` or any function of a class without initializing an object of that class? If yes, then it makes sense to make it static.**

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence is a bit unclear to me. Why create static method here? All `Animal`s `sleep()` and `run()`, they all inherit from `Animal`.

Comment: @dazu I've explained that in updated answer.